# How to correct the “connection.readyState” of mongoose in mocha from “connecting” to “connected?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

When I am trying to run the mocha test i am getting **"Cannot determine state of server"**
since the mongoose connection is in connecting state.

Please suggest how to handle this scenario.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

console.log('conn ready:  '+mongoose.connection.readyState);

// "conn ready: 2"  i.e connecting for test case as well as from user register form 


var Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId,

    UserSchema = new Schema({

       // schemas

    });


UserSchema.statics.newUser = function (uname, email, pass) {

    var instance = new User();

    instance.uname  = uname;

    instance.email  = email;

    instance.pass   = pass;

    console.log("conn state: "+mongoose.connection.readyState); 

    // "conn state: 2"  i.e connecting for test case. But  1  i.e connected for  user register form 

    instance.save(function (err) {
      // Do rest
    });

};

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
exports.User = User;
```

Answer (score 5):

DB connections happens asynchronously so when you check up on it straight after calling `connect` it's likely going to report that it's still connecting. If you want to do something after connection, you need to pass in a callback

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function (error) {
  // Do things once connected
});
```

As for how to handle it in your scenario, my suggestion is to separate connection from your models and connect to MongoDB when required

So if you're testing your user model in mocha, this could be done in the `Before` hook

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Load in your user model wherever that is
var User = require("../models/user");

describe("My user model tests", function () {
  // Connect to mongodb here before you start testing
  before(function (done) {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function (error) {
      if (error) throw error; // Handle failed connection
      console.log('conn ready:  '+mongoose.connection.readyState);
      done();
    });
  });

  // And include disconnect afterwards
  after(function (done) {
    mongoose.disconnect(done);
  });

  // Test your user model down here
  it("passes some tests");
});
```

Depending on how you've structured your app, I'd suggest you move DB connection to a sensible location (e.g. server configuration). When you test your entire app (e.g. integration testing), you would start your server in the `Before` hook

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if you have your mongoose connection routines in another file (like me), during the asynchronous nature of JS, you should wait a little for the readyState to be 'connected' (1). I solved it in 'before':

```
var app = require('../server'); //I have mongoose connection in this file
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var context = describe;

describe('Initial DB routines', function() {

  before(function (done) {
    mongoose.connection.on('connected', done);
  });

  it('Should connect to MongoDB', function(done) {
     mongoose.connection.readyState === 1 ? done(): done(false);
  });
});
```